# Web app to count how many Chrome tabs I have open

Tags: web-apps, chrome

Is there a quick and easy way to see how many tabs I have open? I am using Chrome.

I see that Chrome has some extensions, such as [Tab Count](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-count/cfokcacdaonnckdmopmcgeanhkebeaio?hl=en), which seem to handle this task. But I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a download.

Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because web apps can't do that. There is no Chrome JavaScript API accessible to webpages for interacting with the browser's tab system. The [`chrome.tabs` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) is for extensions only.

Answer (score 6):

What I did was:

1. Go to `chrome://flags/`,
2. Next to the line that reads `mem_usage`, click the <kbd>Expand...</kbd> button,
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl-F</kbd> to open a search box, and
4. Type 'Tab [' into the search box.

[image: Tab search]

Comment: This works too, and doesn't count Gchat popouts, unlike the Tab Count Chrome extension.

Comment: What appears in `chrome://flags` changes rapidly. I don't see anything like it on Chrome 47. You should edit this answer to qualify which versions of Chrome it applies to; I'm afraid very few people use these versions anymore.

Comment: What versions did this originally apply to?

Answer (score 1):

I use [Too Many Tabs](https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Ftoomanytabs-for-chrome%2Famigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp%3Fhl%3Den&ei=mFHrU72HLrCS7AacpoD4Dg&usg=AFQjCNHotdKk2QPaSEhRMP7JMNSjF6XfUg&bvm=bv.72938740,d.ZGU&cad=rja) extension on my Chrome. It's pretty good and does what you need, but still you need to download it; however it's not a big in the size. It's also available for Firefox as it claims.

> Manage your tabs, improve your browsing, and maintain your sanity when you have many tabs open.
>   Ever tried having 20 tabs or more open in Chrome? You can’t even see the favicon of the tabs, not to mention the tab titles! If that happens to you, TooManyTabs is a must-have extension that manages your tabs, reduces your tab overflow, and saves your sanity!

Answer (score 1):

There's no obvious way to get it, but you can try digging into the “hidden” bits.

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> brings up Chrome's task manager. If you then click “Stats for nerds”, a new tab is opened on `chrome://memory`, with a list of all the processes. Chrome often, but not always, uses separate processes for each tab. You can count the number of tab-managing processes by copying the text into an editor and looking for lines containing just `Tab`, or by automating this process (e.g. `xsel -b | grep -xc Tab` under Linux), or approximately inside Chrome by searching for `Tab` (this also counts tabs and extensions whose name happens to contain “tab” as a substring). Once again, this counts the number of tab-managing processes; experimentally, under Linux, there is almost always a separate process for each tab (I don't know when that rule is breached though), whereas the Windows version seems to group a few tabs in a single process quite often.

There's a more reliable built-in way in Chrome 47 which is to open `chrome://memory-internals`, click “Update”, and search for `"history":[{"history":`. Not exactly memorable though, likely to change without notice (unlike the “stats for nerds” thing which is a public if not advertised interface and less likely to change), and doesn't appear to work on Windows.

Another approach would be to parse the `Current Tabs` file in your Chrome profile directory. This isn't a plain text file though, and I don't know if the format tends to be stable.

If it's a casual, one-time thing, another approach would be to count the tabs in each window. To save time, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to go to the 8th tab from the left (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> gets you to the rightmost tab), then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to move tab by tab until you get to the right. This doesn't use any advanced or hard-to-discover tool, but it requires quite a bit of manual tallying, and requires that you go through all your Chrome windows one by one.

All in all, if you often have a large number of tabs, you'll get some benefit from having at least one extension to help you, if only to answer the question “where on earth is the tab with this site?”. I second [Neeku's recommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/10680) of [TooManyTabs for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toomanytabs-for-chrome/amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp?hl=en). I also use a now-discontinued extension called “Tab Menu” (the one mentioned in [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/1zxlk8/anyone_know_what_happened_to_the_tab_menu/), not the [one by the same name which looks more like a poor man's session manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-menu/onmccepingjlmohgnacaibdllchkmamd?hl=en)).